# Is there any way show uninitialized variable being used?

Tags: c++, c, g++, valgrind

```
int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    int b;
    a = b;
}
```

`Valgrind` can not warn me that b is uninitialized.

Comment: You [C compiler certainly should](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed350d3faebf9d91) if you crank up your warnings. Valgrind is a runtime thing; you should be seeking a compile-time thing first.

Comment: It is very likely that both variables were removed by the compiler, so Valgrind will not see them at all.

Comment: Suggest adding code that attempts to use  `a` like `printf("%d\n", a);`  else code same as `int main() { return 0; }`

Answer (score 3):

Your compiler should warn you regaring the uninitialized variable. If it doesn't, maybe the warnings are turned off?

This is gcc (9.3.0) output (with -Wall -Wextra option) :

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:3:9: warning: variable 'a' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    3 |     int a = 10;
      |         ^
prog.cc:5:7: warning: 'b' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
    5 |     a = b;
      |     ~~^~~
```

and this clang (10.0.0):

```
prog.cc:5:9: warning: variable 'b' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
    a = b;
        ^
prog.cc:4:10: note: initialize the variable 'b' to silence this warning
    int b;
         ^
```

Answer (score 2):

Compile it with -Wall flag

```
gcc a.c -Wall -o a
```

Answer (score 1):

Valgrind will only output errors if there is some potential impact on the behaviour of your application. In this case it does not matter that b is uninitialized.

Valgrind is, however, tracking the state of the memory.

If you run

```
valgrind --vgdb-error=0 ./test_exe
```

Then open another terminal and follow the instructions that were printed by Valgrind in the 1st terminal, then you can run commands like

```
mo xb {addess of b} 4
```

See [here](https://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.monitor-commands) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Within the language, there is no way to check for indeterminate values.

In simple cases such as this, compilers can detect it and you can ask to be warned about them. See the manual of your compiler for available warning options.

Compilers also provide "sanitisers" which check for bugs at runtime and are not limited by the complexity of the program as much as the compiletime warnings are. For reads of indeterminate values, a memory sanitiser would be the choice. They don't catch everything though, and the ones I tested did not catch the bug in your program. They could detect it if the indeterminate value was used to control the flow of the program:

```
int a = 10;
int b;
if (b)  // detected by memory sanitiser
    b = a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Community (free) warns:
error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'b' used